# Lagom service test to use real Cassancra

Tags: scala, lagom

I am creating a service test based on this docs: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/scala/TestingServices.html

I don't want to use Lagom's built in Cassandra, so I have this in my sbt file:

```
ThisBuild / lagomCassandraEnabled := false
ThisBuild / lagomUnmanagedServices := Map("cas_native" -> "tcp://...:9042")
ThisBuild / lagomKafkaEnabled := false
ThisBuild / lagomKafkaAddress := "...:9092"
```

but it is not taken into consideration probably, because I am getting this error:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace 'xyz' does not exist
```

How can I make the test use the real db? I assume it is still using Lagom's built in Cassandra.